# Strstr return false instead of true

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fread, strstr

I want to open file, check if string deosn't exist in file write it.

Doing this:

```
$fp=fopen('categories.txt','a+');
$content=fread($fp,filesize('categories.txt'));

if(!strstr($content,$cat)){
    fwrite($fp,','.$cat);
}
fclose($fp);
```

But I got repeating values in categories.txt after writing.
Only issue I can expect is encoding problem, but all files are utf-8 and in `categories.txt` I just have latin symbols and few symbols.

Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can try [mb_strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think problem in `fopen`. I changed to this, and code starts to work:

```
$content=file_get_contents('categories.dat');
$type=(string) $type;
$content=(string)$content;

if(!strstr($content,$type)){
    file_put_contents('categories.dat',$content.','.$type);
}
```

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

try like this.

```
$pos = strpos($content, $cat);
if($pos === false){
fwrite($fp,','.$cat);
}
```

Comment: Same problem with `strpos` and `mb_strpos`.

Comment: i tried with a sample code it worked properly.
can u make sure, before u write something u have made the file clean.